# Magento installation custom folders not loading

Tags: magento, magmi

Hi I have a Magento installation that I've installed MAGMI on top of (MAGMI resides at /magento/magmi/)

I've tried adjusting the .htaccess file but can only get the error to switch from a Magento generated 404 page to a 500 internal server error.

I've also tried adjusting the permissions of the MAGMI folder and files located within to 0777, still doesn't work.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: clear a cache and try again

Answer (score 0):

I think I managed to fix it by adjusting the permissions to 0755 which seems illogical as 0777 would grant higher permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Open your database and search for `core_config_data` Table

```
web/unsecure/base_url set your URL here : http://www.domin.com/directorypath/

web/secure/base_url :  set your secure URL here : https://www.domin.com/directorypath/
```

Feel free to ask if still have any query.